# golang client fails to connect to mongo db server - sslv3 alert bad certificate

Tags: mongodb, ssl, go, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to connect a go client to mongodb server running with ssl enabled. I get a clear error message indicating that the hand shake failed due to ssl error. I use a self signed certificate on the client side.

Got below from the mongodb server:

```
2017-05-13T04:38:53.910+0000 I NETWORK  [thread1] connection accepted from 172.17.0.1:51944 #10 (1 connection now open)
2017-05-13T04:38:53.911+0000 E NETWORK  [conn10] SSL: error:14094412:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert bad certificate
2017-05-13T04:38:53.911+0000 I -        [conn10] end connection
```

Error from Go client:

```
Could not connect to mongodb_s1.dev:27017 x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "crypto/rsa: verification error" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "XYZ")
```

Tried multiple options, but didn't help

Comment: Can you add some code please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip TLS security checks using `InsecureSkipVerify = true`. This allows you to use self-signed certificates. See the code from [compose help](https://help.compose.com/docs/connecting-to-mongodb#go--golang-mongodb-and-compose) below.

Instead of skipping security checks, it is advisable to add the CA used to sign your certificates to the list of trusted CAs of the system.

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "os"
    "strings"

    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
)

func main() {
    uri := os.Getenv("MONGODB_URL")
    if uri == "" {
        fmt.Println("No connection string provided - set MONGODB_URL")
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    uri = strings.TrimSuffix(uri, "?ssl=true")
```

Here:

```
    tlsConfig := &tls.Config{}
    tlsConfig.InsecureSkipVerify = true

    dialInfo, err := mgo.ParseURL(uri)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to parse URI: ", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
```

And here:

```
    dialInfo.DialServer = func(addr *mgo.ServerAddr) (net.Conn, error) {
        conn, err := tls.Dial("tcp", addr.String(), tlsConfig)
        return conn, err
    }

    session, err := mgo.DialWithInfo(dialInfo)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to connect: ", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    defer session.Close()

    dbnames, err := session.DB("").CollectionNames()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Couldn't query for collections names: ", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    fmt.Println(dbnames)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [Official MongoDB Go client](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver), you can use a custom CA by setting the `mongo.Connect(context.TODO(), opts)` options:

```
    caCert, err := os.ReadFile(caFile)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    caCertPool := x509.NewCertPool()
    if ok := caCertPool.AppendCertsFromPEM(caCert); !ok {
        panic("Error: CA file must be in PEM format")
    }
    // Instantiates a Config instance
    tlsConfig := &tls.Config{
        RootCAs: caCertPool,
    }
    opts := options.Client().ApplyURI(uri).SetTLSConfig(tlsConfig)
```

You can also skip verification with

```
    serverAPI := options.ServerAPI(options.ServerAPIVersion1)
    opts := options.Client().ApplyURI(uri).SetServerAPIOptions(serverAPI)
    opts.TLSConfig.InsecureSkipVerify = true
```

Skipping verification is sometimes reasonable when testing but should be avoided.